# Putting Two Code-Point Emoji into String?

Tags: java, scala, char, emoji

Given the following emoji from http://unicodey.com/emoji-data/table.htm:

name: `regional indicator symbol letters ma`

unicode values: `U+1F1F2 U+1F1E6`

What should its code point value be?

Example:

Exclamation point has a code point value of 33, i.e. 0x21 to base 10 = 33

```
scala> "\u0021"
res11: String = !

scala> "\u0021".codePoints.toArray
res12: Array[Int] = Array(33)
```

So, in this case, I could simply put `\u0021` into a String. But, how can I create a `String` to contain the `regional indicator symbol letters ma`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can construct the String:

```
scala> val points = Array(0x1F1F2, 0x1F1E6)
points: Array[Int] = Array(127474, 127462)

scala> val string = new String(points, 0, points.length)
string: String =
```

---

*Edit: below part was my original answer which I hope will be helpful to someone*

I think you slightly misunderstand how the that "emoji" works.  If you compare the `:flag-ma:` which you are interested in to the `:flag-mc:`

[image]

You'll notice that the first portion of the unicode is the same `U+1F1F2`, which corresponds to the letter "m".  What this means is that you're actually not dealing with a single emoji, its actually two separate ones which, when in a certain sequence, are displayed as a given flag.

As an example, here is how the GB emoji (`U+1F1EC U+1F1E7`) is rendered on certain platforms (notice how it isn't always a flag): [image]

Comment: But why does `s` have 4 code points?

`scala> val s = "\u1f1f2\u1f1e6" | scala> s.codePoints.toArray` returns 
`res45: Array[Int] = Array(7967, 50, 7966, 54)`